If I perform a cleanup activity after a delay would that affect my working?
Inspired by this post, if we remove the Event Listener in cleanup after a delay does the previous reference of the Event Handler still gets attached to the browser?
Here is the code :
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
// import React from "react";
// import "./style.css";
import { useState, useEffect,useRef } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [userText, setUserText] = useState('');
// Any event handler (function in JS) declared with (){} will be a new
// object in every render. So for every render hanleUserKeyPress is assigned a 
// new reference
  const handleUserKeyPress = event => {
    const { key, keyCode } = event;
    if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
      // When this function is added as event listener to any browser activity
      // The entire code gets snapshotted i.e for every activity userText would
      // remain same.
      // For any browser activity added to this tag it will see :
      // const handleUserKeyPress = event => {
      //   const { key, keyCode } = event;
      //   if (keyCode === 32 || (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90)) {
      //     console.log('Value of userText : ' + '')//Added as snapshot
      //     console.log('Value of userText + key : ' + ''+key)
      //     setUserText(''+key);
      //   }
      // };

      console.log('Value of userText : ' + userText)
      console.log('Value of userText + key : ' + userText+key)
      setUserText(userText+key);
    }
  };


// This runs on every render(no dependency declared). 
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleUserKeyPress);
    return () => {
      // Add a delay to see 
      async function fun(){
        await delay();
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleUserKeyPress);
      }
      fun();
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Feel free to type!</h1>
      <blockquote>{userText}</blockquote>
    </div>
  );
}
function delay(){
  return new Promise(resolve =>{
    setTimeout(()=> resolve(),5000)
  })
}

So when initially the setup runs, React takes snapshot of the userText state inside handleUserKeyPress and is added to keydown event.
When a key is pressed(lets say 'k'), setUserText is called and hence rendering of the component will take place with value (''+'k' = 'k'). After the code gets committed to the browser DOM, cleanup should run. But here, I am providing a delay of 5 seconds. During this time if I am pressing any key the previous version of the Event Handler is still added to keydown event. And hence any key(suppose 'm') that is pressed before 5 seconds gets over, would fire the handleUserKeyPress function with userText as '' and hence console should print 'm' and not 'km'. Also userText should be set as 'm' rather than 'km'.
Where I am getting it wrong?

Your code creates a new "keypress" event listener every time the component renders, and because you are delaying the removal of existing listeners this means that more than 1 keypress event listener can be live and listening at any given moment.

During this time if I am pressing any key the previous version of the
Event Handler is still added to keydown event. And hence any
key (suppose 'm') that is pressed before 5 seconds gets over, would
fire the handleUserKeyPress function with userText as '' and hence
console should print 'm' and not 'km'. Also userText should be set as
'm' rather than 'km'.

This is the exact behavior that I think you should expect to see, but I think you are misunderstanding the console logs. Here's some example log output with annotations:




Event
Description





Component mounts and creates keypress listener #1


"k" pressed
"k" is pressed, keypress listener #1 console logs output "" + "k" -> "k", a userText state update is enqueued to "k", the useEffect hook cleanup function is called and enqueues the timeout, the component rerenders, and keypress listener #2 is added with "k" in closure


within 5 seconds "m" pressed
"m" is pressed, keypress listener #1 console logs output "" + "m" -> "m", a userText state update is enqueued to "m", keypress listener #2 console logs output "k" + "m" -> "km", a userText state update is enqueued to "km", the useEffect hook cleanup function is called and enqueues the timeout, the component rerenders, and keypress listener #3 is added



Each state update simply overwrites the previous state, so you miss the "intermediate" state value of "m" since it's immediately overwritten by "km" and the component rerenders with that current state value.

But the setup of useEffect will run after cleanup, so till 5 seconds is over though a new event listener is created, it is not added to keydown as setup has still not run.

@boggy Yes, the effect cleanup function runs immediately, but you've placed the actual cleanup to occur after 5 seconds has elapsed. In the mean time later effects are free to continue adding keypress listeners. I think your confusion here is that maybe you are thinking the timeout blocks the next effect from adding a listener.

Yes but I got it now, the cleanup perform it's task of calling the fun and removing the event listener is scheduled to be removed after 5 seconds. But JS continues to run setup.
